# How to throw an exception with indent?

Tags: javascript, exception, throw

Is there any way to `throw` javascript errors and force it to be indented?
Instead of `'Error'` to be `'  Error'`. If not, what can I use instead, that will surely exit my node.js process. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: I am watching a folder for file changes, and I am compiling files with a specific format to another. When a change accure, I have a whole process going, so I try to log out it in readable format.
filename.json: [
logs
errors
outputs
].
To make it better I want to add indents, but I use throw, which has no indents, and I may not exit the whole process.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the way node displays an uncaught error. But, you can catch the error and choose to display it however you want, before exiting your program.

```js
class SpecialError extends Error {}

function main() {
  // ...
  throw new SpecialError('Whoops!')
}

// This is at the very end, so when the catch finishes,
// there's nothing left to execute, and the program ends.
try {
  main()
} catch (err) {
  if (!(err instanceof SpecialError)) throw err
  console.error([
    `      Error: ${err.message}`, // Lots of indentation
    ...err.stack.split('\n').slice(1)
  ].join('\n'))

  // Makes the program exit with status code 1. See here: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exitcode
  // Uncomment this when you're in node.
  // process.exitCode = 1;
}
```

Comment: I am using chokidar to watch files, and I need to exit the child script only, but when I use process.exitCode or exit, it quits the whole process.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your setup. But, process.exitCode shouldn't cause anything to exit. It just says "when node exits, use this status code". An uncaught error, on the other hand, does cause the program to exit with an error status code set (which is what you originally had).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I realy understood your question, but did you try something like this?

throw new Error('\tSome error message.');

Comment: Yes, it shows 'Error:    Some error message'.